# one post per term taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, query-posts, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I need some help, again.

I use this query:

```
$tax = get_the_terms($id, 'coupon_category');
                    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                    query_posts( array(
                        'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'posts_per_page' => 4,
                        'tax_query' => array( 
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', // Taxonomy
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug, // Your category slug
                            ),
                            array(
                            'taxonomy' => APP_TAX_STORE,
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $term->slug,
                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                            ),
                        ),                      
                    ) );
```

I know need a solution to only show one post from each Taxonomy term `APP_TAX_STORE`. Tried some solutions from this userfull forum but non worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah sure.

```
<?php 
                    $included_post_ids =array();
                    $args = array(
                      'post_type' => 'APP_POST_TYPE',
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'posts_per_page' => 1,
                      'tax_query' => array( 

                          array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'coupon_category', // Taxonomy
                          'field'    => 'slug',
                          'terms'    => $tax[0]->slug, // Your category slug
                          ),
                    ),
                  );
                  $custom_posts = get_posts( $args );
                  if( !empty( $custom_posts ) ){
                    foreach ($custom_posts as $key => $postObj) {
                      $included_post_ids[] = $postObj->ID;
                    }
                  }
                  //Similar proceduce for other taxonomies 
                  $args = array(
                    'post__in' => $included_post_ids,
                    'post_type' => 'APP_POST_TYPE',
                  )
                  $final_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
                  if ( $final_posts->have_posts() ) {
                  }
```

?>

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. Unfortunately if I us this code my page is blank and giving me errors. I did include the closing `?>`

Comment: Please let me know which error is showing on your page?

Comment: Please also make sure that you have replaced the terms with your term slug in the code. And please remove the closing PHP tag ( ?> ).

Comment: Just the header is showing. And I can not add a term slug because it's changing.

Comment: Please turn on the debugger by changing the code in wp-config.php. Please see the link => https://help.one.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005594045-How-do-I-enable-debugging-in-WordPress- 
for step by step instructions. In this way you can see the error showing on the page.

Comment: Thats what I did, and thats the strange thing. Even the admin bar is gone on the page with this code.

Comment: I think you have broken your code. Can you please post all your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89206/discussion-between-joloshop-and-mohsin-ghouri).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the only one post of each taxonomy in a single query. You have to get the single post by using `posts_per_page=> 1` for each term and then use the `post__in` to get the one post of each taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you, okay new to this can you give me an example?

Comment: Code is so long. We have not much space to write the code in the answer of the comment so I have published another answer with the example of the code. please check.

Comment: Sorry I was offline. However there is still a misunderstanding. I would like to post 4 posts all together. Within this 4 post there should be only once a post from each `APP_TAX_STORE` Taxonomy

Comment: I have replied you in the chat. please check.

Comment: Change it still nothing